# Ruby JSONP returns Errno::EPROTONOSUPPORT

Tags: ruby, ajax, jsonp

This one is driving me nuts.
I have two websites who have to talk to each other trough JSONP.

Site A checks in its database if some value is present and returns json data {"result":"Found in library"} if found.

When doing a cURL from the command line, I get my data as expected.

Doing a Ajax call from site B, I can see in the logging of site A that the request is handled correct, but site B complains about "Unexpected end of data at line 1" The inspector shows me no data at all, so I assume that is the problem. Where did the data go?

As I don't want the inner workings of the Ajax call to be reveiled, I want to do it in the Ruby controller with a Net::HTTP call.
Again, I can see in the logging of site A that the call is handled correct and returns the result.
This time, Ruby logging shows:

> Errno::EPROTONOSUPPORT (Failed to open TCP connection to xx.domain.com:443 (Protocol not supported - socket(2) for "xx.domain.com" port 443)):

My controller in site B:

```
  def query
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {
        # Submit Ajax call
        uri = URI(base_url + "/data_subjects/query.json")
        data = {
          key: api_key,
          parmA: params[:parmA],
          parmB: params[:parmB],
        }
        uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(data)
        logger.info("QUERY: #{uri.inspect}")
        res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
        render :json, JSON.parse(res)
      }
    end
  end
```

My controller in site A:

```
  def query
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {
        .... Do some stuff
        if $rc == 1
         render json: {:result => I18n.t("result_found")}, status: :ok , :layout => false
        else
          render json: {result: I18n.t("result_not_found")}, status: 404, :layout => false
        end
      }
    end
```

As I said, using cURL everything looks okay, but with either jQuery or Ruby it fails.

> UPDATE

Okay, found it!
As it turns out, you need to specify ":callback => params[:callback]" to the json response:

```
render json: {:result => I18n.t("result_found")}, :callback => params[:callback], status: :ok , :layout => false
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri).body`?

Comment: @casper unfortunately not.Same error. I'm wondering if the jsonp callback isn't working. When specified on the cURL command it makes no difference, but specifying it in the Ajax call it doesn't seem to get called.

Comment: If you found the solution you can answer and approve your own question. That way others will find the answer also if they have the same problem later.

Comment: Well, the problem is partly solved. Doing a jQuery Ajax call works, but calling it from a Ruby controller returns the EPROTONOSUPPORT error.

Comment: The call you are making is going to port 443. That's an SSL connection. Perhaps check if in general you're able to make SSL requests with Ruby. `Net::HTTP.get_response(URI('https://www.google.com/'))`? Something screwy with SSL and your Ruby setup?

Comment: @Casper Thanks, I think you nailed it. SSL support is no issue, but I now realize that the server is in a FreeBSD jail behind a reverse proxy. And the jail itself has no IPv6 support. The called server is on IPv6 only, so that explains a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was triggered by not having IPv6 support in the FreeBSD jail in which the calling process runs. And the server which was called only has IPv6 connectivity.